# Development of Website (CMS - Joomla) + App Development (language, such as kivy?), which is the best combination?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'll start to develop a new website with Joomla (a multilingual site, with user-profiles) and want to be able to develop an application later on working well with the site (ideally with kivy, given that I'm experienced with it and that it works on all platforms). Do you may recommend any other language for the app development which works well with a multilingual website developed with Joomla ? Cheers

Comment: Before we receive too many more posts from you, please take a moment and visit the [tour] page.  More specifically, please read about the types of questions that you shouldn't ask here at the [help/dont-ask] page -- see the bottom of that page where there is a grey area about this site's tolerance for _subjective_ questions.

Comment: By application I assume you mean a mobile app? If so, I think you should use whatever language you are most familiar with. A lot of the hurdles involved in making Joomla work with a mobile app will be similar regardless of the language ( I think).